# Alembic + Sqlalchemy Multi Column Unique Constraint

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm attempting to create using sqlalchemy a multi column unique constraint that will be picked up by Alembic in it's automatic upgrade script generator.

I have create the constraint using:

from sqlalchemy `import UniqueConstraint` in my model

```
UniqueConstraint('col1', 'col2', 'number', name='uix_table_col1_col2_col3')
```

However, this is not picked up by Alembic in it's automatic script generation.

I can manually create this in the Alembic script by adding in.

```
op.create_unique_constraint('uq_table_col1_col2_col3', 'table', ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Is there a way to have this be automatically generated by Alembic?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 34):

I was experiencing the same problem and found that if you're defining the table using the declarative model, you can add it the unique constraint to `__table_args__` and Alembic will pick it up:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('col1', 'col2', 'number', name='uix_table_col1_col2_col3'),
    )
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that:

```
....
        __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('col1', 'col2'),)
....
```

Adds the following to an alembic upgrade file:

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_unique_constraint(None, 'instruments', ['col1', 'col2'])
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```